# After clicking a picture, i am not able to see it in ImageView

Tags: android

I am able to connect to the camera, and take pictures. I can see where my file are been loaded,the directory. But, i am not able to view it in my app.
Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_photo);

    takePhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.click_photo_button);
    image= (ImageView) findViewById(imageView);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        takePhoto.setEnabled(false);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE }, 0);
    }

}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            takePhoto.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

I have added Camera and Write to External Storage permission as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="edu.android.notetakingapplication">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".AddPhotoActivity"
        android:label="@string/addphoto">

    </activity>
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
</application>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem will be in onActivityResult. If you take a look at [photo basics](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) you can see a preview of the image is returned in the Intent data, which you can use if this is all you require is a tiny image.

Otherwise, the step you are missing is conversion to a content URI (this is what the gallery works from). Either when you take the photo (as explained in the page I linked):

```
Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.example.android.fileprovider", file);
takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
```

Or perhaps later, in your onActivityResult (I haven't tested this works):

```
//remember to change the package
image.setImageURI(FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.example.android.fileprovider", file));
```

Comment: Thanks Bud! Worked awesome. I messed up with package name while getting URI for file.

Comment: Great! Just for my info - did it work just doing it from onActivityResult?

Comment: I did it by adding the package name manually instead of     file = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", createFileDir()); Ill check via onActivityResult and let you know.

Comment: Got an error on the setImageURI line :
W/ImageView: Unable to open content: content://edu.android.notetakingapplication.provider/external_files/Pictures/NoteTaking/IMG_20170226_142846.jpg -----
W/ImageView: resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: content://edu.android.notetakingapplication.provider/external_files/Pictures/NoteTaking/IMG_20170226_142846.jpg (Sorry for the format, not used to add code snippet in comments)

Comment: About what I expected. I figure that function creates a new row in provider db when you save the file, thanks for trying it